# How can I start the Sessions in android

Tags: android, session

I want if the user want to connect to his user panel and then if the user copied the the contents of the address bar and again if the user want to log out and now again if the user want to connect to his user panel by copying the contents of the address bar, as the result the user should not be able to open his user panel.I searched in internet and I understood that I should use the **Sessions**.

Please see the following code. When I search in internet about **Sessions and php** I find something like the following:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
echo "Session variables are set.";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

As you see, Session is inside the `php tag` and `php tag` is inside the `HTML tag`. The problem is that to use the **Sessions** we can not use `php tag` in `java` codes.